# Deposit Ether into a Contract

Tags: contract-development, remix

I added the below three functions to my deployed contract as described in the article https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/

I deployed using Remix on Rinkeby.  When I enter 1 Ether into the Deposit transaction in Remix I get the "Gas Estimation Failed" Error.

Why is the Deposit function generating an error?

Thank you[image]

function withdraw() public {
msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}

```
function deposit(uint256 amount) payable public {
    require(msg.value == amount);
    // nothing else to do!
}

function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

**Update**

I tried to use a fallback function but Remix is not liking it.

pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Attach the full contract code including your solidity version.

Comment: That is a very weird function and in my opinion doesn't make any sense for learning purposes. Furthermore, your example is from three years ago which is an eternity in blockchain world - I suggest you use some more recent tutorial

Answer (score 1):

1. I used the below fallback function and it worked.

`receive() external payable {}`

2. This post was what I was actually looking for in my original question.  Everything works well now.

[How do you send Ether as a function to a contract using Remix?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46107/how-do-you-send-ether-as-a-function-to-a-contract-using-remix)